# How to commit the files which were pushed before and abandoned in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

Suppose i have three files - `file 1`,`file 2` and `file 3`. I add them, commit and push it. It goes to the gerrit system,and suppose i find that i had to change something in the `file 1` I abandon the patch in gerrit. In my local system I edit the `file 1` and do git status then it will only show `file 1` as modified.

My problem here is to push the modified file(`file 1` in this case), `file 2` and `file 3` in a single patch and push it.

If I do git pull it will say `already up to date`.

I tried `git reset <previous commit id>` then add my changes and push it. which would work fine but I don't know if its the right method.
Can anyone help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why did you abandon the change?

Gerrit was specifically designed for this purpose that you review your changes, see that file 1 needs to be changed, then you modify your file 1 and submit this again as patch 2

It is correct that the `git status` shows that only file 1 has changed. It compares to you local repository, not to gerrit.

The right way to do this is to make sure you have the [commit-msg hook](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/cmd-hook-commit-msg.html) for gerrit in your local git repository hooks folder. This will add a Change-Id to your commit messages. With this gerrit can track which commits are related to the same change.

1. Initial change, commit files 1-3: `git commit -a`
2. Push to gerrit: `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`
3. Modify file 1
4. **Amend** your last commit to update file 1: `git commit -a --amend`
5. Push again to gerrit: `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`

Now your modification will show up as patch 2 and you repeat steps 3-5 until you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

No need to abandon the change.

What are the changes you need, you can do it and follow the below steps.

- Note : Make sure that `git log` was showing your most recent commit
  or not.

> 1. git status - it will show the modified files.
> 2. git add . or git add ***modified_file_names***
> 3. git commit --amend (to make modifications to the most recent commit)
> 4. git push origin HEAD:refs/changes/***change_id***
>      Ex: git push origin HEAD:refs/changes/1125642 (This will submit again    as next
>
> patch set.)